# How to integrate a Silverlight app into Azure Cloud?

Tags: silverlight, azure, azure-web-roles

I have found this excellent tutorial on this topic, yet it leaves some open questions  http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-in-the-Azure-cloud-Part-1.aspx

When creating a new Azure Cloud project with empty roles:

1. Is it better to add the existing Silverlight Web Project as a
   Webrole as its suggested in the blog?
2. Or is it better to create a new WebRole and connect that with
   the Silverlight Client instead?

The reason I am asking, is that I need to make use of the override OnStart() method within my WebRole to execute a piece of task after the role went up and running.  The required class WebRole.cs obviously exists only in the step 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to you can simply copy in or create a new WebRole class; it's just a class that inherits RoleEntryPoint. The Windows Azure runtime will always reflect across your deployed role looking fior a class that inherits RoleEntryPoint; this is the same for both web and worker roles.

I tend to advise customers to keep their Silverlight project as a seperate project and to deploy the *.xap file via Blob storage rather than out of the web role. It is, at the end of the day, just another statis resource and the Blob storage approach has the benefits of a) Not chewing clock cycles serving a static file and b) easier to light up to use the CDN whic will make end user expereince a bit nicer.

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for your response. Thats great news that I can simply add that file and could therefore stick with solution 1). Regarding your additional comments. I see your point of having the XAp file on the storage. That way if the client is updated but not the service, we just copy the xap over and its done. Correct me if I am wrong, but if the Service Side gets updated we cant get around updating the whole VM instance anyway, correct?  Therefore if database/service access is required for the silverlight app, you need the backend sitting there and chewing clock cycles anyway.

Comment: What did you mean by CDN please? Thanks

Comment: Thanks Richard. CDN sounds promising to speed up the access to the xap file. However CDN would work fine for media files and xap (client). But the back-end (Web project that connects to database etc) still needs to run on a Azure VM instance, correct?